# vscode for web production deployment

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the difference between "./scripts/code-web.sh" and "./scripts/code-server.sh --launch"? It both see vscode in the browser. Any tutorial to publish the vscode in a production server such as apache? Or it has to stay with its built-in web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [how to contribute documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute) you can see the following definitions:

1. VS Code for the Web(./scripts/code-web.sh) - Extensions and UI run in the browser
2. Code Server Web (./scripts/code-server.sh --launch) - UI in the browser, extensions run in code server (NodeJS):

Here it's an image the will describe the [Code Server Web Arhitecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSC1p.png), you can find some additional information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server).

[image: Code Server Web Arhitecture]

But for me, everything resumes at 2 significant points:

1. Using Code Server Web I can access the terminal
2. Through the terminal I can use the OS functionalities